# Have both Gremlin-Server AND NEO4J Server running at the same time

Tags: neo4j, gremlin-server

Current it seems we cannot run both **Neo4J Server** and **Gremlin Server** at the same time. Is there any way to have run both?

1. NEO4J is running and I try to start to Gremlin Server then I get the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this
>   Graph implementation [class
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph].......................(truncated)

2. Gremlin Server is running and I try to start NEO4J Server then I get the following error

> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Store and its lock
>   file has been locked by another process:
>   /home/galaxia/Documents/neo4j-gremlin/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock.
>   Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the
>   directory is writable (required even for read-only access)

---

Versions

- Neo4J 3.3.1
- Gremlin 3.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run them together that way (i.e. embedded mode), but it should be possible to run them together, if you either:

1. Configure the Neo4j graph in Gremlin Server to use HA mode as described [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_high_availability_configuration)
2. Configure the Neo4j graph in Gremlin Server to use the Bolt implementation found [here](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt)
3. Enable the Bolt protocol in the Neo4j properties file provided to Gremlin Server.

As an example of the third option, given the default Gremlin Server packaged configuration files for Neo4j, you can edit `conf/neo4j-empty.properties` to include:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph
gremlin.neo4j.directory=/tmp/neo4j
gremlin.neo4j.conf.dbms.connector.0.type=BOLT
gremlin.neo4j.conf.dbms.connector.0.enabled=true
gremlin.neo4j.conf.dbms.connector.0.address=localhost:7687
```

and then start Gremlin Server with `bin/gremlin-server.sh conf/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml` at which point you can use standard TinkerPop drivers as well as standard Bolt connectivity against the same graph instance.

Comment: HA didnt work because I am in Community Edition, will try Bolt

Comment: Bolt is by 'SteelBridgeLabs', is it the official library?

Comment: that implementation is not maintained by neo4j and i'd expect slower than HA, but those are the only two methods by which you can make this work that I know of.

Comment: Been trying out the bold plugin for a while, not finding any way to use it with TinkerPop Python API. the bolt implementation they have made is Java specific. any way out?

Comment: If you configured the bolt graph implementation in Gremlin Server as a graph instance, then the gremlin-python connects to Gremlin Server and makes all graphs available to it (including the bolt one)

Answer (score 3):

I realize it has been a while, but I *finally* figured this out and thought others should know.  As Stephen Mallette said, you can use the Bolt implementation.  To configure this for Gremlin Server, use the included `gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml` file and make the following change:

```
graphs: {
  graph: conf/neo4j-bolt.properties}
```

Then create the `neo4j-bolt.properties` file with this content:

```
gremlin.graph=com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.Neo4JGraph
#neo4j.graph.name=graph.db
neo4j.identifier=dummy
neo4j.url=bolt://localhost:7687
neo4j.username=neo4j
neo4j.password=<password>
neo4j.readonly=false
neo4j.vertexIdProvider=com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.providers.Neo4JNativeElementIdProvider
neo4j.edgeIdProvider=com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.providers.Neo4JNativeElementIdProvider
```

Remember to replace the password, and any other property with the correct values.